# JSP: How can I use expression tag in println in scriptlet tag

Tags: java, html, oop, jsp, servlets

The tag got complicated during development.

So I can't determine if this code is grammatically incorrect or if I made a mistake.

Can you look at the code I posted and see the problem?

I uploaded it in image and text format.(I included the image format because it would be more intuitive.)

This is the code I want to fix(67 line in updateAction.jsp):

```
"location.href = 'view.jsp?bbsID=<%=bbsID%>'"
```

Here is image format:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AegBO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yghqL.png)

And here is Text format:

```
script.println("<script>");
//script.println("location.href = 'view.jsp?bbsID=<%=bbsID%>'"); -> my wrong code
//script.println("location.href = `please enter code here`");
script.println("</script>");
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi , try like this `script.println("location.href = 'view.jsp?bbsID="+bbsID+"'");`

Comment: @Andreas I thought I shouldn't just upload the image, and I could attach the text together. But from now on, I will only attach text:) Thank you for letting me know the rules of the site.

Comment: @Swati Oh It's work! Thank you!

Comment: What is bbsID? a request attribute? a session attribute? something else?

Comment: @MauricePerry The attribute is obtained from request.getParameter()

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this:

```
String bbsID = request.getParameter("bbsID");
script.println("location.href = 'view.jsp?bbsID="
        + URLEncoder.encode(bbsID, "UTF-8") + "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you used %> in `"location.href = 'view.jsp?bbsID=<%=bbsID%>'"`  it may have closed the opening scriplet tag <% in your code. It is not there in the image you have uploaded but assuming that the complete code is something like below, it might be cause of error you are getting.

`<% ................... ................... "location.href = 'view.jsp?bbsID=<%=bbsID%>'" ......... %>`
If you use `System.out.println("location.href = 'view.jsp?bbsID=<%=bbsID%"+">'");` , error should not occur though resolution already provided by Swati is better.